# Problems with libsvm data

Tags: java, libsvm

i am using LibSVM to classify data for my project. SVM uses numerical format of the data to classify. Does anyone know how to convert the data to numerical format so that the data is able to be pumped into the LibSVM?

Comment: have you tried google?

Comment: yea. but i am trying to do it in a way that i do not have to use command line

Comment: what format is your data in?

Comment: Text or String format

Answer (score 0):

Check the question "How to convert other data formats to LIBSVM format?"
at this link:

[Lib SVM FAQ](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/faq.html#f307)

Specifically for your question, this tool I found can also help. It converts a **text data set into a numerical dataset**:

http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libshorttext/doc/converter.html